# Eclipse Style Navigation In VS.Net 2008 IDE

Tags: visual-studio

I'm a Java developer starting with .Net development using VS.Net 2008. I would love to get the Eclipse style of navigating methods etc by pressing the Ctrl key, hover over a method then click it to got to that method's declaration. Does such a plugin exist for VS.Net 2008?

thanks

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/168369/eclipses-crtlclick-in-visual-studio

Comment: Actually http://stackoverflow.com/questions/80857/in-visual-studio-2008-how-can-i-make-controlclick-do-a-go-to-definition may be even better.

Answer (score 0):

To summarize [In Visual Studio 2008, how can I make control+click do a “Go To Definition”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/80857/in-visual-studio-2008-how-can-i-make-controlclick-do-a-go-to-definition), you could either use [AutoHotKey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) with the following script,

```
SetTitleMatchMode RegEx
#IfWinActive, .* - Microsoft Visual Studio
^LButton::Send {click}{f12}
```

or use [ReSharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/).

Answer (score 0):

Two ways to go to a method's declaration:

Press F12 when the cursor is positioned in a call to the method.

Right click a call to the method and select 'Go To Definition' on the popup menu.